# (index):17 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

How is this missing a ) after the arguments? Have I gone blind?

```
const data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("alphabet.csv").text(), d3.autoType);
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-0XfwGD1nxplHpehcSVI7lY+m/5L37PNHDt+DOc7aLFckwPXjnjeA1oeNbru7YeI4VLs9i+ADnnHEhP69C9CqTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test D3</h1>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3</p>

    <script>
        const data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("alphabet.csv").text(), d3.autoType);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is likely due in order to `await` something you need to have an async function. create a async function then invoke it:

```
<script>
  async function getData() {
    const data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("alphabet.csv").text(),d3.autoType);
  }
  getData()

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this gives me another error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: @MasterSmack I updated my answer. I tested in a sandbox. The error was gone once I created an async function

Comment: I can't get this to work either, it gives me this error:
(index):18 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: FileAttachment is not defined
    at getData ((index):18)
    at (index):21

This works for you?